# Errors loading tensorflow (.pb) model into c# (Tensorflow.NET)?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow, computer-vision

I'm new to tensorflow.NET and I am currently following the documentation online ([TF.NET](https://tensorflownet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ImageRecognition.html)/[Example](https://github.com/SciSharp/SciSharp-Stack-Examples/blob/master/src/TensorFlowNET.Examples/ImageProcessing/RetrainClassifierWithInceptionV3.cs)) to import my trained CNN model from python into c#.

So far I've imported my protobuf (.pb) file into c#, but I get errors when trying to set the input and outputs of the model (lines 23 and 24).

> Unhandled exception.
>
> System.Exception: Can not convert a String into a Operation.
>
> at Tensorflow.Graph._as_graph_element_locked(Object obj, Boolean
>   allow_tensor, Boolean allow_operation)
>
> at Tensorflow.Graph.as_graph_element(Object obj, Boolean allow_tensor,
>   Boolean allow_operation)
>
> at Tensorflow.Graph.get_operation_by_name(String name)

After looking online it appears to be something to do with multi-threading or parallelism, however, I've yet to find a solution to it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Here is my current code implementation:
[image]